# New table for Primary/Foreign key Relationship in ORMLite

Tags: orm, ormlite, android-sqlite

I have a User table with the following details in my android DB
username, password, email, mobile,

I have another table named Service with the following detail in my android DB
service name, service category, service description

Now, I want to associate the relationship for every user (eg: username) with his/her service (service name) using ORMLite.
I want to maintain a seperate table for this relationship. Now, my question goes like this

1. Is is possible for ORM that it generates a table if I specify the primary key and foreign key relation, such that it can populate the data for every service getting added ?
2. Do I have to create a bean maintaining the common fields between my user table and service table and do the insertion task manually whenever a new service is added ?

-Thanks
Srikant

Comment: I googled and followed this link
http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC29.

Comment: It helped me and now my questions is solved. Hence closing the post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have solved you own problem but I'll still answer for posterity.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) calls this relationship between `User` and `Service` a "foreign object" fields.  Here's the [documentation for foreign objects](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-object).  It sounds like `User` is associated with a service so your `User` class would have a `Service service;` field.  Something like:

```
public class User {
    ...
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true)
    private Service service;
}
```

Now your questions:

> Is is possible for ORM that it generates a table if I specify the primary key and foreign key relation, such that it can populate the data for every service getting added ?

ORMLite does *not* handle foreign key limitations although you can tune the schema yourself to add it.  If you setup the foreign key then it will use the primary key from `Service` in your `User` table.

> Do I have to create a bean maintaining the common fields between my user table and service table and do the insertion task manually whenever a new service is added ?

Not sure I understand the question.  All you need to do is create your `Service` using the `serviceDao` and then add the server to your `User` before creating it using the `userDao`.